# What is the difference between a receptive field and a feature map?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, comparison, terminology, feature-maps, receptive-field

In a CNN, the *receptive field* is the portion of the image used to compute the filter's output. But one filter's output (which is also called a "feature map") is the next filter's input.

What's the difference between a receptive field and a feature map?

Answer (score 11):

#### Feature map

A **feature map** is the output of the convolution operation (performed by a convolutional layer).

When you apply a kernel $K_1$ to the input image $I$ (i.e. you perform the convolution operation with $K_1$), you produce one feature map $F_1$. We can denote this operation by $F_1 = I \circledast K_1$. Note that [the convolution (or cross-correlation)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21999/2444) can be seen as the multiplication of the kernel $K_1$ with different sub-regions of the image $I$. Each of these multiplications produces a scalar value of the feature map $F_1$.

If you perform another convolution operation with another kernel $K_2$, you produce another feature map $F_2$. So, if you perform the convolution operation $n$ times with $n$ different kernels in a convolutional layer, you will get $n$ feature maps, which are typically concatenated to form a block of feature maps, which we can denote by $\mathbf{F}$. So, the total number of feature maps is equal to $n$, i.e. the number of kernels that you convolve with $I$.

Each element of a feature map $F_i \in \mathbb{R}^{w \times h}$, which we can denote by $F_{i_{jk}}$ (i.e. the element at coordinates $j$ and $k$ of the matrix $F_i$), can be thought of as the "**activation** of a neuron".

Alternatively, you can think of a feature map as a collection/map of *features* produced by the kernel $K_i$ (hence the name *feature map*). In other words, $K_i$ extracts certain features from $I$. Another kernel $K_l$ may extract other features, and so on.

#### Receptive field

A **receptive field** is the portion of the input image that is/was used to compute the **activation** of a neuron (aka node) in a feature map.

So, we talk of "the receptive field of a neuron in a feature map". You can read [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/25850/2444) to understand more what a neuron in a convolutional layer is.

#### Illustration

This illustration should summarise the descriptions above.

[image]

In the illustration above, a feature map is a 2-dimensional matrix of shape $46 \times 46$. There are $100$ feature maps (so $100$ kernels were convolved with the input image). The receptive field of a neuron (small pink square in the feature map) is a 3-dimensional sub-region of the image of shape $5 \times 5 \times 3$. Note that, in this case of a 2d-convolution, the kernel has the same depth as the input image (i.e. $3$).

#### Receptive field of neurons in deeper layers

The output of a convolutional layer, which we denoted by $\mathbf{F}$ above (i.e. the concatenation of all feature maps), is the input to the next layer of the CNN. If this layer is a convolutional layer, then it will produce other feature maps $\mathbf{F}'$. The receptive fields of the neurons associated with these feature maps $\mathbf{F}'$ will not correspond to the receptive fields of the neurons associated with the feature maps produced by the first convolutional layer. In fact, as you go deeper into a CNN, the receptive field of neurons increases. You can read more about how it increases [here](https://blog.mlreview.com/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807) or watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70A3uYfM1qA). That's why we can think of neurons in deeper layers as "looking at more general features of the input image".