# What is meant by sub-region of an image?

Tags: definitions, image-processing

Consider the following sentences from the research paper titled [PatternNet: Visual Pattern Mining with Deep Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06339.pdf) by *Hongzhi Li et al*.

> The value of each pixel in a feature map is the response of a filter
> with respect to a **sub-region of an input image**. A high value for a
> pixel means that the filter is activated by the content of the
> **sub-region of the input image**.

The sentences mention the **sub-regions of an image**. Is there any formal definition for a sub-region of an image?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they are informally using the term "sub-region" to refer to the section of the image with which you multiply the kernel to produce a scalar value of the **feature map** (which they call *pixel*, but I would use the term *pixel* only to refer to the scalar values of the image). So, it seems that a sub-region is a synonym for **receptive field**. We have a question on the difference between receptive fields and feature maps [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/8701/2444).